# Progress bar with PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have written the following code that parses a text file, breaks it into tokens and inserts these tokens into the database. I want to show the current status of the process using the progress bar but the following code isn't working.

I wrote the following code based on this [How to connect pyqtSignal between classes in PyQT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891465/how-to-connect-pyqtsignal-between-classes-in-pyqt)

[`yast_gui.py`](https://github.com/jarifibrahim/YAST/blob/master/yast_gui.py)

```
class YastGui(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    incrementTokenSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    ...

    def __init__(self):
        self.incrementTokenSignal.connect(self.increment_token_count)
        ...

    def increment_token_count(self, val):
       msg = "{}/{}".format(val, self.total_db_records)
       self.ui.records_processed_value_label.setText(msg)
```

[`yast.py`](https://github.com/jarifibrahim/YAST/blob/master/yast.py)

```
class LogFile(object):
    def __init__(self, file_path, YastGui_object):
        super(LogFile, self).__init__()

        # Gui object
        self.gui = YastGui_object
        self.total_db_records = 0
        ...

    def tokenize(self):
        for i, record in enumerate(myfile):
            ...            
            self.gui.incrementFilterSignal.emit(i + 1)
            settings.session.commit()
```

According to this [PYQT and progress Bar during Long Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951988/pyqt-and-progress-bar-during-long-process), I should create QTheads to deal with the progress bar but I'm not sure on how to do it.
Here is the entire [Gui file](https://github.com/jarifibrahim/YAST/blob/master/yast_gui.py) and [main file](https://github.com/jarifibrahim/YAST/blob/master/yast.py).

Comment: You could provide a manual to test the program and help you

Comment: You could provide examples of the files that are imported by the gui.

Comment: @eyllanesc You can find the code here https://github.com/jarifibrahim/YAST. You might not understand the code as the project is still in progress. To run it try `python3 yast_gui.py`

Comment: Of course, I have executed it, but it asks me to pass a file, passing it any file sends me an error.

Comment: @eyllanesc The input file is an Apache web server log file with the common log format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem here [Change the value of the progress bar from a class other than my GUI class PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415737/change-the-value-of-the-progress-bar-from-a-class-other-than-my-gui-class-pyqt4?rq=1).

The trick is to pass the `progressBar` object to the function as a parameter and then use `progressBar.setValue()` inside that function.